# How do the new Dark Eldar interact with the Kill Team rules in the Battle Missons rulebook?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The [Battle Missions book](http://www.games-workshop.com/gws/catalog/productDetail.jsp?prodId=prod630003a&rootCatGameStyle=), near the end, features a scenario called Kill Teams, wherein:

Your force org chart is:

- 0-1 elite
- 0-2 troops
- 0-1 fast attack
- 200 points.

Exact Rules:

> **Every man For Himself:** All models operate as individual units in this mission, even if they were chosen as part of a squad or squadron.  In addition, when a model shoots or fights in an assault, it may split its attacks up amongst any eligible targets if desired.

The issue:  The new [Dark Eldar](http://www.games-workshop.com/gws/content/article.jsp?aId=12500034a) are very dependent on their Pain Token abilities.  These grant "pain tokens" to the squad at certain times (1 to start, and gain additional ones for wiping out other units).  Are the pain tokens now tracked 'per model'?  Or still shared among the whole squad?  Do you now gain pain tokens for each model killed, or just when you wipe out all the models that make up an enemy squad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is nothign in the Kill Team rules that says individual models are considered to be a single squad of 1, then I would say the pain tokens are given to the entire squad (a squad being one elite, troop or fast attack choice) for wiping out an entire enemy squad.

However, if the Kill Team rules explicitly state that each model is conisdered to be its own squad, then I would say pain tokens are given on an individual model basis for each model they wipe out.

Comment: I will check the exact wording and post clarification.

Comment: Posted the exact rule.

Comment: @GWLlosa -- The phrase "even if they were chosen as part of a squad or squadron" to me implies that even though you may have 10 Dark Eldar Warriors in a squad operating as individual units, they are still considered a squad.